# Jasper reports date conversion

Tags: jasper-reports

I am having some problems with date/time representation. The data collection creates an 
XML file containing dates/time in the format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

For example:

```
<from>2012-01-10 12:59:00</from>
<till>2012-01-10 17:00:00</till>
```

I have seen one case where the conversion was incorrect in the German locale:

```
2008-10-15 12:59:24 converted to 15.10.08 00:59:24
```

It has been suggested that the input date format is incorrect, and so I tried the closest
standard I could find (ISO-8601) and input yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss. This resulted in an exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2008-09-30T23:22:27"
```

so I guess taht wasn't it!

I have two questions:

```
1 - Is the date format the problem???
2 - If it is, what is the default date format (I have read the documentation but 
    didn't find it)
```

Comment: No, the date format is not a problem. Your question is unclear - too few details. What did you use (Java code or just iReport)?

Comment: What was the format String you used for the incorrect output you posted in the question? And of course the answer to Alex's question.

Comment: In answer to the above: The jasper report code imported many modules from "net.sf.jasperreports.engine" and called with the data XML and some XML which specified the report (Didn't see "date" or "time" mentioned anywhere. The incorrect outupt came from within the jasperreports engine.

Comment: I'm beginning to think I should raise a bug with jasper reports, does that sound reasonable???

Comment: Have you checked that field's text field pattern? As far as I understood from your question, your pattern should be: dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss